# Reason behind TP99 spikes on deployment to website

Tags: java, deployment, web

I am hosting a website which allows users to login .. create their widgets by adding some best selling products . I am seeing TP99 spikes whenever I do some deployment to this site. Can someone provide me any pointers on what should be the reasons for TP99 spikes and what should I be looking at ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deployment of code to the server-side is always expensive.  Depending on how exactly you are doing it, the overheads *may* include:

- cost of creation of a new classloader,
- cost of loading the new versions of the classes ... or all classes in the 'webapp',
- cost of webapp shutdown and restart overheads,
- cost of JIT compiling new classes / versions of classes,
- garbage collection of old classes, old class statics, etc.

If you provided more information (are these server-side widgets, are they being deployed, how they are being deployed, etc) maybe I could give a more specific answer.

Comment: Also, if there are JSPs in the mix and they aren't precompiled, there's the overhead of compiling JSP code to Java and then bytecode too (and then compiling that to machine code, but you already mention that).